# ruby if statment for js.erb file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

Could anyone assist me in setting up my js.erb file to cover two scenarios.

At the moment i have infinite scroll working when the page initially loads, but when i change the params the new collection loads fine but when i scroll down the page to load the rest of the results i just get the next set of 6 objects replacing the last, rather than appending them onto the end

rehome.js.erb

```
$('.all_animals').append("<%= j render @animals %>");
 <% if @animals.next_page %>
  $('.pagination').replaceWith('<%= j will_paginate @animals %>');
 <% else %>
  $(window).off('scroll');
  $('.pagination').empty();
 <% end %>
```

Javascript

```
function infiniteScroll() {
 if($('#infinite-scrolling').size() > 0) {
 $(window).on('scroll', function(){
 //Bail out right away if we're busy loading the next chunk
 if(window.pagination_loading){
  return;
 }
   more_url = $('.pagination a.next_page').attr('href');

if(more_url && $(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 50){

//Make a note that we're busy loading the next chunk.
  window.pagination_loading = true;
  $('.pagination').text('Loading.....');
   $.getScript(more_url).always(function(){
    window.pagination_loading = false;
  });
 }
 });
} 
}
```

So on page load i call the function

```
$(function(){
 infiniteScroll();
});
```

and as a ajax success callback

```
success: function(data) {
     infiniteScroll();
   }
```

When the ajax call is made the params :rehomed are always present so i could wrap the separate logic in

```
<% if params[:rehomed].present? %>

<% end %>
```

does anyone have any ideas for dealing with the newly loaded content in my rehome.js.erb file

Thanks

Update

So on page load i need this to be the logic

```
$('.all_animals').append("<%= j render @animals %>");
 <% if @animals.next_page %>
  $('.pagination').replaceWith('<%= j will_paginate @animals %>');
 <% else %>
  $(window).off('scroll');
  $('.pagination').empty();
<% end %>
```

and when an update is made to the collection i need

```
$('.all_animals').empty();
$('.all_animals').append("<%= j render @animals %>");

<% if @animals.next_page %>
 $('.pagination').replaceWith('<%= j will_paginate @animals %>');
<% else %>
 $(window).off('scroll');
 $('.pagination').empty();
<% end %>
```

How to combine them into one statement is what im trying to work out

Comment: Why do you need pagination if there's an infinite scroll? I mean, what is pagination menu for ( `$('.pagination').replaceWith('<%= j will_paginate @animals %>');` )?

Comment: Use a js variable to know this is first request(page load or update) and use above code with that variable.
var firstLoad = true;
success: function(data) {
     firstLoad = false;
     infiniteScroll();
   }

Then in js.erb
if !(firstLoad){
$('.all_animals').empty();
}